# MultiversX integration into unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, authentication, multiversx

I can't find anything on the official repo of MultiversX about a unity SDK. Does someone already implemented xPortal login in a unity project ?

Comment: Better to ask Elrond team directly

Answer (score 0):

There is no official SDK yet. I managed to login with xPortal in Unity3D.